# Why do i see configurations at simple product and how can i remove it in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product

There's a section where i can add Configurations even when i choose to Add Simple Product and i'd like to remove it.

There's another section with a title Downloadble that i was able to disable by change the code in its Composite.php file.

from:

```
        DownloadableType::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE,
        CatalogType::TYPE_SIMPLE,
        CatalogType::TYPE_VIRTUAL
```

to:

```
        DownloadableType::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE,
        CatalogType::TYPE_VIRTUAL
```

i was looking for a similar solution but the code is different.